# Can starlight be described as a light beam?

Tags: visible-light, photons, stars

I would like to study starlight propagating in the universe. Can I model the light as a beam with a radius $r$ and a unit wave vector $\hat {\mathbf k}$ with a frequency distribution $f(k)$? Also, the light beam shares the same radius $r$ with its emitter (the star), and since $r$ is large enough, I could ignore beam divergence.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. Starlight from a given star?

Comment: @anna v   Yes, light emitted from a given star.

Comment: What do you mean by a "beam" ? Radiation from most stars (ignoring edge cases like neutron stars etc.) is emitted more or less uniformly in all directions, so it does not form a beam in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: @gandalf61, ...but after you pass some of that light through an aperture...?

Comment: @gandalf61 I am considering a place which is far from the star. Then only photons with the same unit wave vector can reach that place. Can those photons as a whole be treated as a light beam? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what @gandalf61 was thinking, but I'm _guessing_ that what we call a "beam" of light is defined by what happens at its edges. The rays of light that a distant star casts upon the Earth are parallel for all practical purposes, but there are no edges to that field of light. That's why I asked about an aperture. Let the starlight pass through a clean hole in a thin card, and you will have artificially created a pencil beam with edges. I don't know enough about wave mechanics though to talk about what happens at the edges of that beam.

Comment: Thanks, @SolomonSlow . Are the edges essential? I am studying the wavefront of light, so I am considering a plane that is perpendicular to some direction $\hat n_k$ and is far away from the star. I think only photons parallel to that direction can reach the plane. Therefore, can I treat the light as a beam, even though I do not introduce an explicit edge here?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the answer.